# How to create symbolic matrix and do substitute in batch with sympy?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, python-3.5

I need to create completely symbolic matrices, are there ready made functions for that in `sympy`?

For example, if I were to create a 2x2 matrix manually, I would do

```
from sympy import *

a00, a01, a10, a11 = symbols('a00 a01 a10 a11')
A = Matrix([[a00, a01],[a10, a11]])
```

The problem is I do not know the dimension prior to simulation and creating every symbol manually gets old fast when dimension gets higher. Ideally I want to be able to create a 10x10 matrix with `A=Matrix(10,10)` with `A[0,0]=Symbol('A00')`, etc.

Also, if the above is possible, it'd be really nice to be able to do substitution in batch as well. For example, I want something like `some_equation.subs([(A,numpy.random.rand(2,2))])`

Comment: so `MatrixSymbol` seems to do the job but what about the substitution part?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `subs` method to do the substitution.

```
In [5]: A = MatrixSymbol('A', 2, 2)

In [6]: B = MatrixSymbol('B', 2, 2)

In [7]: C = A*B

In [8]: C.subs({A: Matrix([[0, 1], [1, 0]]), B: Matrix([[2, 3], [4, 5]])})
Out[8]: 
Matrix([
[0, 1],
[1, 0]])*Matrix([
[2, 3],
[4, 5]])
```

Probably you need symbolic dimension for your `MatrixSymbol` objects.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have been trying to make all the elments of a matrix separate symbols?
Here's something I tried to make an array rho that is "states x states" in size:

```
rho = np.array([[Symbol("rho{}{}".format(i,j)) for j in range(len(states))] for i in range(len(states))])
```